# How to fill down when the fill handle isn't working?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I frequently run into an issue where Excel doesn't want to cooperate with filling a formula down thousands of rows. Double clicking the fill "handle" does nothing (wrong data type? wrong file type? who knows), and dragging down seems to be the only option. This is problematic when we're talking about thousands of rows.

How else can I fill down when the fill handle isn't working?

Answer (score 4):

It took me long enough to discover the "name box." Turns out it's a great place to specify a cell range that you want to modify.

[image]

Here's one thing you can do when the fill handle isn't working:

1. Paste the formula into the topmost cell of the column you want to
   fill
2. Click the namebox and enter the range you want to fill down and
   hit Enter
3. Press CTRL+D ( or Command+D if you're on Mac) to fill down

That's a shortcut that has saved me hours that I'd otherwise be dragging and dragging.